# How do I pass argument to a Java 8 Lambda stream function?

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am new to Java 8 Lambda, so I may not be familiar with the correct terminology. Please point me in the right direction and I will make the necessary changes in my question. So here it is:

I have written a java lambda function that does a lot of manipulations, however I am struggling with just one bit.

Code:

```
 final List<JsonNode> curatedArticles = chubRelatedVideoArticles.stream()
            .filter(this::isValidRelatedVideoArticle)
            .filter(this::dedupeOGArticle)
            .map(this::convertChubRelatedVideosIntoMcsRelatedVideos)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now for all the functions used above it is fine to not pass the param, e.g. as it uses "this". So the function signature is:

```
private boolean isValidRelatedVideoArticle(final ChubRelatedVideoArticle article)
```

Now, I would like to pass a string to the dedupeOGArticle along with the "final ChubRelatedVideoArticle article" as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a lambda:

```
.filter(article -> this.dedupeOGArticle(article, "some string"))
```

Comment: This worked, thank you so much, will mark as answer (Once I am allowed to).